# TimeSpan imprecision in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, timespan

I developed a windows service that runs a task from time to time. However, the task execution interval is every hour. However, I am noticing that the task is being executed approximately every 1 hour and 5 seconds, and this is a problem.

I understand that Windows is not a real-time operating system, but don't you think the inaccuracy is too great, adding 5 seconds to the set interval?

I try to use `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)` and `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600)` and I have the same result.

I need to use `System.Threading.Timer` because only this class has the possibility of applying a delay to first execution.

Basically I use:

```
_timer = new Timer(DestFunction, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delaysec), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600));
```

What can I do, to keep the execution in same second every hour?

Comment: _" the task is being executed approximately every 1 hour and 5 seconds"_ - how do you determine that?

Comment: what do you have delaysec set to?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the constructor. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-threading-timer-ctor(system-threading-timercallback-system-object-system-uint32-system-uint32)) that delay is used when the callback is invoked....which sounds like its going to have that delay every time

Comment: @GuruStron i have a log file with timestamp executed functions. And i see the 1:05 between executions.

Comment: @Narish, the duetime works in first callback execution

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the precision of `TimeSpan`. It is due to how the operating system allocates runtime to the service and the time it takes for the service to wake up, etc.

I suggest to calculate the delay from the next planned execution date/time and the current date/time. Like this, these unwanted delays will not sum up.

```cs
DateTime next = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromHours(1);

// Truncate minutes and seconds. I.e., make it a full hour.
next = new DateTime(next.Year, next.Month, next.Day, next.Hour, 0, 0);
TimeSpan delay = next - DateTime.Now;
```

Of course, you could add minutes to the calculated `next`, if you don't want to execute the task at the full hour. e.g. at 15 minutes past every hour:

```cs
next = new DateTime(next.Year, next.Month, next.Day, next.Hour, 15, 0);
```

If this is still not precise enough, you could shorten the delay by a few seconds and then loop until the expected time.

```cs
DateTime next = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
next = new DateTime(next.Year, next.Month, next.Day, next.Hour, 0, 0);
TimeSpan delay = next - DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

//TODO: Start your timer or schedule your task somehow.
```

When the  timer event fires or the task resumes:

```cs
while (DateTime.Now < next) {
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
// TODO execute the task
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it. Timed events do not actually need additional timers; you just need to keep track of the system clock.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving a log file with timestamp.
Maybe those 5 seconds are delaysec or the service time to start.